# Why is K-topology on $\mathbb{R}$ finer than a standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there sets in the K-Topology that aren’t open in the standard topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279027/are-there-sets-in-the-k-topology-that-arent-open-in-the-standard-topology)

Of course this sounds like some materials from Munkre's book, but I still do not get why K-topology (collection of sets of the form $\{(a,b) \setminus K=\{\frac{1}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N} \}\}$ is finer than the standard topology.

It is easy to show that the lower limit topology is finer than the standard topology, but I am stuck on the case for K-topology.

Comment: I just wonder is there a way to prove that K-topology is strictly finer than standard topology in a direct way, i.e not using the example in the thread given?

Comment: Exhibiting a set that is open in the $K$-topology but not in the Euclidean topology is about as direct as a proof can get!