# Confusion b/w the structure of standard topology on $\mathbb R$ & the structure of K-topology on $\mathbb R$ i.e,$\mathbb R_K$.

Tags: general-topology

I'm confused b/w the structure of standard  topology on $\mathbb R $ i.e,$\mathbb R $ & the structure of K-topology on $\mathbb R $ i.e,$\mathbb R_K $

Since, standard topology on $\mathbb R$ is generated by (a,b),whereas the K-topology on $\mathbb R$  $(a,b)\cup(a,b)-$K.

But,$(a,b)\cup(a,b)-$K=$(a,b)$.

Therefore,standard topology on $ \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R_K$ are generated by the collection of open intervals on the real line.Hence,**Standard topology on $\mathbb R$=$\mathbb R_K$**.

But,this result is wrong,as $\mathbb R_K$ is strictly finer than the Standard topology on $\mathbb R$ .

**NOTE**

> **$K-$topology on $\mathbb R$**==let $K$ denote the set of all numbers of the form $1/n$,for $n \in \mathbb Z_+$,and let β′′ be the collection of all open intervals (a,b),along with all sets of the form (a,b)−K.The topology generated by β′′ will be called K−topology on R
>
> **Standard topology on $\mathbb R$**==let β be the collection of open intervals in the real line,$(a,b)={x:a<x<b}$, the topology generated by  β is called the standard topology on $\mathbb R$.

Help me in clearing this concept,i've just started studying topology.

Comment: What is the $K$- topology?

Comment: @Aweygan:let $K$ denote the set of all numbers of the form $1/n$,for $n \in \mathbb Z_+$,and let $\beta'' $ be the collection of all open intervals $(a,b)$,along with all sets of the form $(a,b)-K$,The topology generated by $\beta''$ will be called $K-$topology on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Don't you think that would have been important to mention in the body of your question?

Comment: @Aweygan:I thought that these are the standard terminologies.But,anyways i'll mention it & sorry for inconvenience( :->).

Comment: It's fine, but the notation $K=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is not standard, nor (as far as I'm aware) is the notation $K$-topology, for an arbitrary subset $K$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279027/are-there-sets-in-the-k-topology-that-arent-open-in-the-standard-topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $U=(-1,1)\setminus K$ open interval in $\mathbb{R_k}$ but it is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: :thanks for your response but your answer can help in showing $\mathbb R_K$ is strictly finer than the standard toplogy on $\mathbb R$ (with which i agree).My problem is if $\mathbb R_K$ & standard toplogy on $\mathbb R$  are generated by same objects,then why they are considered different?

Comment: They are not generated by the same objects the biases are different. My advice see Munkers page 82. We will see the argument.

Comment: :it will be better if you edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

@amWhy & Battani:How can $(-1,1)\setminus K$ is open in both $\mathbb{R_K}$ & usual  topology in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry, I mean, it is not open in $\mathbb {R}$